# telerik kendo and bunble MVC at the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm involved in a MVC .Net project and Telerik Kendo.

This is a sample of how to use Kendo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1315/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This code work perfectly. One of the requirements of my project is get a nice score on google speed test page. To do it I have to move the Javascript files to the end of the page. Like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1315/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
</body>
</html>
```

But in this approach I get a Javascript error: **jQuery is not defined** becase the code generated from this second sample look like this:

```
<body>


<h2>Index</h2>


    <input class="k-input" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" type="date"><script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({"format":"M/d/yyyy","min":new Date(1900,0,1,0,0,0,0),"max":new Date(2099,11,31,0,0,0,0)});});
</script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1315/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1315/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>



</body>
```

My question is: How can I avoid this error ?

Comment: Move `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` to the end (after the 2 `@Scripts.Render(...)` lines of code

Comment: @StephenMuecke - That won't work either. This is a limitation of how Kendo's components render in the client. They need at least jQuery to be loaded in the page before the page renders. The rest can come at the end: http://www.telerik.com/forums/load-kendo-scripts-on-bottom-of-page---possible

Comment: @JustinNiessner, Not familiar with Kendo, but it should be done anyway - any scripts within the view (inside the `@section scripts {`) that use jquery may not work unless wrapped in document.ready

Comment: go old school and just use the kendo javascript instead of the MVC helpers to build your controls :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you need deffer the kendo control.
Try `@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Deferred.Name("datepicker"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your datepicker control after all js files loaded - put following line into a js file and refer this js file on you page.

```
jQuery("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({"format":"M/d/yyyy","min":new Date(1900,0,1,0,0,0,0),"max":new Date(2099,11,31,0,0,0,0)});}
```